# SharePoint Document Library File Upload Customization

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I am looking for ways to customize SharePoint Document Library File upload behavior in SharePoint Online. Instead of using out of the box (OOB) file upload, custom component where we can have some logic before uploading a file is required. Can we customize/replace OOB file upload behavior? Any guidance in this regard is very much appreciated. Thank you.

I have no clue on how to approach this requirement. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the default "upload" using the format view customization. Check out:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZYZnJGQgcI

As a second step, you could provide your own version of the upload button (by building a "command bar extension")

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api

Alternatively, you could provide an application (built using PowerApps for example), that is specific for your users instead of customizing the document library user interface. This looks a bit more reasonable than breaking the built-in UI, IMHO :)